# How to use SemanticModel to check if variable has been tested?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm working on a [Roslyn extension](https://github.com/tomlokhorst/codeanalysis-checknullable) to warn against unprotected `.Value` accesses of `Nullable<T>` values.

This provides the following behaviour:

[image: Warning: "Nullable 'x' must be checked for null values before accessing 'Value' property"]

This extension already sort of works, but the code to test if an access is "safe" is sort of a hack. I now simply walk the syntax tree, [looking for `if` statements](https://github.com/tomlokhorst/codeanalysis-checknullable/blob/87904d91479f40b5c290d1766c808efc6ee8cf0b/src/CheckNullable/DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs#L58).

This approach is quite ugly and produces a bunch of invalid warnings.

Here are some examples of cases where access `x.Value` should be safe:

```
int y;
int? x = foo();

y = x != null ? x.Value : 42;

if (x > 4)
  y = x.Value;

if (x != null && someExpr) // With && only one branch needs to be a test
  y = x.Value;

if (x == 3 || x == 4) // With || both branches must be a test
  y = x.Value;

if (x == null) return; // Exit method body before access .Value
y = x.Value;
```

Is there a way to use the `SemanticModel` to properly write this test?

One of things I'm thinking about is to do [Abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) over the syntax tree. But that seems like a lot of work, and I'm hoping a full blown abstract interpreter is not needed.

I'm not quite sure how dead code analysis is implemented in Roslyn, but it seems somewhat related to this.

Comment: I think your example with the note has a bug: if bar == true and x == null, this will crash. The || operator should be symmetrical in terms of "safety", I would think (although the left hand side might imply safety on the right hand side).

Comment: That should be `&&`, not `||`

Comment: And what you're asking for is called Reachability Analysis.

Comment: Roslyn's implementation is internal, and can be found at http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/FlowAnalysis/DataFlowAnalysis.cs#58

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Right, thats was a bug. I fixed the example.

Comment: @SLaks: the implementation is a public API, you can just call SemanticModel.AnalyzeDataFlow. Tom needs something stronger though.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played with Roslyn at all, yet. But being a user of ReSharper which has this exact feature as well, I can do the following statement:

My observation is that ReSharper only looks to the last recent usage of the respective symbol (type Nullable<>). This is an iterative proof. If the variable has been used (obviously) successfully, it is safe for continuus usage. Then it is up to the previous usage check to proove that this again is a safe access. Thus: check the previous access for either another previous access or a salvaging comparison against null to see if it is safe.

```
if( x != null)
     x.access
```

Example:

```
var z = x.Value; // unsafe because it is first and un-tested
var y = x.Value; // safe because it is not first and therefore dependent on first access
```

Comment: I like your idea (or ReSharpers ;-)) but isn't it more of an optimization than an actual solution to the problem? You'd still have to prove that the first access to the variable is safe or a null check (either explicit by != null or HasValue or implicit by comparison, non-null assignment etc.).

Comment: It probably ends up in beeing a recoursive problem. So to say: prove the first access and the further are safe.

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem requires flow analysis, which Roslyn doesn't yet do.